# PostgreSQL Search Query - Check empty fields

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to create the search system with mutliple criteria fields. My question is how to handle the empty criteria fields (omitted by user). I need to check what if the variable is empty in order to implement the AND condition. In my case, the last name is required, so I just have to check id first name and ID are not empty fields:

```
$query ="SELECT first_name, last_name FROM students  WHERE last_name ILIKE '%$last_name%' ";


if(isset($_GET['$first_name']))
$condition[]="first_name ILIKE '%$first_name'";

if(isset($_GET['$ID']))
$condition[]="ID = '$ID'";



if(!empty($condition))
$query .= implode(' AND ',$condition);

$result = pg_query($query);
```

this doesn't work.

Comment: where are you setting your `last_name` field from the `$_GET` value

Answer (score 1):

i think you are missing an `AND`

```
if(!empty($condition))   
    $query .= ' AND '.implode(' AND ',$condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the variables that you are requesting from the GET are wrong, they have a `$` symbol after the name.

Also you can print the Query before executing it to see if it well formatted.

Try this and post the result please.

`$query ="SELECT first_name, last_name FROM students  WHERE last_name ILIKE '%$last_name%' ";`

```
if(isset($_GET['$first_name']))
$condition[]="first_name ILIKE '%$first_name'";

if(isset($_GET['$ID']))
$condition[]="ID = '$ID'";


if(!empty($condition))
$query .= implode(' AND ',$condition);
echo $query; exit();
$result = pg_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic should work, but it seems you have a lack of basic PHP syntax and principles.

I'm guessing you have:

```
<input type='text' name='ID' />
```

Not

```
<input type='text' name='$ID' />
```

So therefor you should use `$_GET['id']`.

---

The next thing, it seems like you're counting on [registered globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) which is deprecated in new versions of php.

You should use:

```
$condition[]="ID = '" . $_GET['ID'] . "'";
```

---

[You're not escaping income values](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), use [`pg_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php):

```
$condition[]="ID = '" . pg_escape_string( $connection, $_GET['ID']) . "'";
```

---

You're not initializing `$conditions` array, add:

```
$conditions = array();
```

to the beginning of your script

---

You're missing `AND` when you're building final query:

```
if( count( $conditions)){
    $query .= ' AND ' . implode( ' AND ', $conditions);
}
```

Or alternatively you can add `last_name` to `$conditions`:

```
$query ="SELECT first_name, last_name FROM students  WHERE ";
$conditions = array(
    "last_name ILIKE '%" . 
         pg_escape_string($connection, $_GET['last_name']) . 
         "%'"
);
// ...
$query .= implode( ' AND ', $conditions);
```

Comment: "lack of basic PHP syntax"

Comment: @Vytkor nothing it is quite humorous at this time of night. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Pomm's Where](https://github.com/chanmix51/Pomm/blob/master/Pomm/Query/Where.php) class. It allows you to easily create AND / OR criterias and bind them with values in order to escape them. This way you can use multiple selection lists and join them with an OR clause and join those with other criterias with ANDs.